# Mistake in the computation via partial fractions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

This is a computation made in Titchmash's Introduction to Zeta functions. I was trying to reverse the computation. However, I kept missing factors.

Consider $\frac{1- xyz^2}{(1-z)(1-xz)(1-yz)(1-xyz)}$. This is the trick used to compute $\frac{\zeta(s)\zeta(s-a)\zeta(s-b)\zeta(s-a-b)}{\zeta(2s-a-b)}$ where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function. I always miss $1-xyz^2$ in partial fractions.

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-xz)}=\frac{1}{1-x}(\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{x}{1-xz})=f$$

$$\frac{1}{(1-yz)(1-xyz)}=\frac{1}{1-x}(\frac{1}{1-yz}-\frac{x}{1-xyz})=g$$

So $(1-xyz^2)fg$ is the original expression. It suffices to consider $fg$. There will be 4 terms with quadratic denominators. Consider $(1-x)^2fg=(\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{x}{1-xz})(\frac{1}{1-yz}-\frac{x}{1-xyz})$ instead.

There are only 2 terms containing $\frac{1}{1-z}$.

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-yz)}=(\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{y}{1-yz})\frac{1}{1-y}$$

And

$$-\frac{x}{(1-z)(1-xyz)}=-\frac{x}{1-xy}(\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{xy}{1-xyz})$$

Now combine $\frac{1}{1-z}$ coefficients. $\frac{1}{1-y}-\frac{x}{1-xy}=\frac{1-x}{(1-y)(1-xy)}$.

However I do not see removal of $(1-xy z^2)$(i.e. $\frac{1}{1-xy z^2}$ did not show up anywhere in the computation.)

The final step in the book gives $\frac{1- xyz^2}{(1-z)(1-xz)(1-yz)(1-xyz)}=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-y)}(\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{x}{1-xz}-\frac{y}{1-yz}+\frac{xy}{1-xyz})$.(If one starts with partial fraction between $\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-xz)}$ and $\frac{1}{(1-yz)(1-xyz)}$, then the desired result can be achieved.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Where is the mistake in above computation?(Say I only care to trace error from $\frac{1}{1-z}$ coefficients. The computation of those coefficients should be independent of each other.)

Comment: I don't follow: there isn't any $\frac1{1-xyz^2}$ in the partial fraction.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The partial fraction final answer should be removal of $1-xy z^2$ part.(If I believe the expression is unique, then it should coincide with the final step of the book.)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I guess appropriate question is where have I missed the factor $\frac{1}{1-xyz^2}$.

Comment: You seem to have got half-way through the calculation and then given up. What happens if you keep going?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I did the computation yesterday for all 4 terms 2 times. However, I did not observe $\frac{1}{1-xyz^2}$ showing up in any of them.(This terms has to show up if the answer in the book is correct and I checked it did show up in a different computation I did.) That is why I felt something very wrong going on in my computation.